# Finding facebook user identifier, who liked a page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

[image]

[image]

I have facebook like button on my webpage. When someone clicks to like it, then is there any way to know who liked it, any facebook user identifier?

Also, if someone has already liked that and coming back to my page, then is there anyway to know that the visitor has already liked it and what is that visitor's facebook unique identifier?

Pl. assume, user is already logged into facebook.
I read about FB.Event.subscribe at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe but that just tells me that someone liked my page, but there is no way to know "WHO"

I have flexibility to change the button to link or anything else, as long as I can get unique identifier.

Comment: If you only use facebook like button in your page, you cann't get user data.
So, you can not know that who liked your link.

Comment: No, you can't. Although that's something that seems to be more irrelevant, users still have some privacy on the internet. If you want to get the users ID you must create an app and ask every user that enters your site for permissions, then it's up to users to grant you that info. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Answer (score 0):

Something I built couple years ago so not sure if it's still working considering Facebook changes it's API frequently. Maybe you can tweak this a little or maybe it gives you some new ideas of how to retrieve the userId:

```
var pageID = "@Configuration.FbPageID",
    appID = "@FacebookApplication.Current.AppId",
    returnURL = "@Configuration.FbReturnURL";
    OAuthResponse = {},
    fbReturnHandler = function () {
        if (!$.isEmptyObject(response)) {
            OAuthResponse = response.authResponse;
            isFan();
        }
    },
    isFan = function () {
        if (!$.isEmptyObject(OAuthResponse.accessToken)) {
            FB.api("me/likes/" + pageID + "?access_token=" + OAuthResponse.accessToken, function (r) {
                if (r.data.length) {
                    window.location = "/@ViewBag.Language/Home/step2?uid=" + OAuthResponse.userID;
                }
            });
        }
    };

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: appID, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
        if (!$.isEmptyObject(response)) {
            OAuthResponse = response.authResponse;
            window.location = "/@ViewBag.Language/Home/step2?uid=" + OAuthResponse.userID;
        }
    });

    if ($.isEmptyObject(OAuthResponse)) {
        FB.ui({
            client_id: appID,
            method: 'oauth',
            scope: 'user_likes',
            redirect_uri: returnURL,
            response_type: 'token'
        });
    } else {
        isFan();
    }
};
```

The `returnURL` is a dummy page which handles the OAuth request and returns the value of the response to your application. Since it doesn't automatically close, you can work around it by adding a small script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.opener) {
        window.opener.fbReturnHandler();
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

The like button is in XFBML:

```
<span class="fb-like"><fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/yourfanpage" send="false" width="49" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like></span>
```

Apparently this can be HTML5 these days: generate [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button).

As stated in the comments, to get a userId you'll have to go through some facebook policy (scope) to allow the user to share this information with your application. Therefor it's required to [build your own application](https://developers.facebook.com/) on facebook.

After your application is setup, I found the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to be very helpful in getting the proper `pageId` and `appId`. Don't get confused by the ID in the URL when browsing FB apps, fanpages ...

The `OAuthResponse` object fetches the access token, required for your application to allow sharing information. Once succesful, you'll find the userId in `response.authResponse.userID`.

Similar information can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/).

Comment: Thanks @tim for the snippet. But I am not having any app for it. Rather it is just to be on a random webpage.

Comment: That's fine but your simple webpage can still have an app on facebook just to detect if a user has liked a page or not. An app on facebook becomes nothing more than a contract between facebook and your simple webpage.

Comment: adding an app will require users to grant permission to my app. And that is an added layer of onus, that I don't want to present to my users